# Running Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to run a jsp page from a Dynamic Web Project I created in Eclipse (using Tomcat web container). When I do it on my work computer and works fine, however when I try to run it on my MacBook Pro, all I see is this in the console:

```
JUnit version 4.10

Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)
```

When I right click the jsp page it only displays "Run Configurations" rather than "Run As...".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is that the "Dynamic Web Project" Facet is enabled on that project on that computer. (I find that when copying/migrating Eclipse projects from one computer to another, I often have to fix settings like that....)

To check facets: right-click on the project, click "Properties". Click "Project Facets" in the left-hand column. Verify that "Dynamic Web Module" is checked.

Note that if "Project Facets" does not appear in the Properties dialog, there will be a few extra steps -- a Stack Overflow search will help out here.

Comment: How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Facet information is stored in the .settings folder of the project.  That and the .project file are needed if you are copying or sharing the project across systems (you might have to tweak some things to make the project more portable).